# Not able to identify the checkbox element ::before and ::after in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pseudo-element

[image]
I want to click on the checkbox. Tried different methods. But not working. Any solution?

@FindBy(xpath="//label[@for='Tnc']")
Still its not getting the exact element of check box. Instead it is clicking on the Terms and Coniditions hyperlink and opening the pop up page.
I wanted to click on the Chcekbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use following `xpath` to identify the element, which is checkbox element.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='Tnc']")
```

Comment: Already tried that it is giving following error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable            xpath: //input[@id='Tnc']]